# JavaScript reference html5 semantic tag

Tags: javascript, html, nav

I'm new to JavaScript and this site. I need help with trying to toggle a div's visibility, the `div` is a html semantic tag (`nav`), and I can't find a way to reference it.

I have searched for a good hour and have tried `document.getElementById()`, but that doesn't work unless I change the tag to `<div id="nav">`.

My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
"use strict";

var e = document.getElementById(id);

if (e.style.display === 'block') {

    e.style.display = 'none';
} else {

    e.style.display = 'block';
}}
```

And I'm calling it from another div in my html like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('nav');"><div id="mNav"></div></a>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href=""><li>
            Link 1
        </li></a>
        <a href=""><li>
            Link 2
        </li></a>
        <a href=""><li>
            Link 3
        </li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nav` is not id in your case, but a tag name. In this case, use:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName(id)[0];
```

Or, more flexible solution:

```
var e = document.querySelector(id);
```

(also, as it's not id, you probably want to replace `id` parameter with `tag`, but that's just cosmetic :) )

Comment: Is there a big difference between the two approaches above?

Comment: @Ash The first solution is only to apply changes to the first nav in the body, the second applies the changes to all the navs.

Comment: It works brilliantly, can't believe I couldn't find this anywhere else. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your case `document.getElementById` is used only if the element has an ID. But if you want to get reference of the element using tag name, then you must use `document.getElementsByTagName`. But again this would make your generic function `toggle_visibility` to be limited to tagname.

Instead of both, use `document.querySelector`. To this function, you can pass css selectors and it can be either id or tag name or class name as well.

```js
function toggle_visibility(selector) {
   "use strict";
   var e = document.querySelector(selector);
   e.style.display = (e.style.display==="block") ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('nav');">Toggle Menu<div id="mNav"></div></a>

<nav>
<ul>
    <a href=""><li>
        Link 1
    </li></a>
    <a href=""><li>
        Link 2
    </li></a>
    <a href=""><li>
        Link 3
    </li></a>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Also instead of binding the click event to the element inside the HTML, use `addEventListener` to bind the event. It would be easier for you to manage.

Now in your HTML you can even reference like:

```
toggle_visibility("#myNav")
toggle_visibility(".className")
```

Comment: Does using (e.style.display==="block") ? "none" : "block"; do anything different to the way I structured mine?

Comment: Nope, both are same. Just used a ternary operator in this